# AudioStreaming a mediafile from web

Tags: android

I want to make simple audio streaming application but my this code is throwing exception.
Can anybody tell me whats wrong?

```
***public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
       String url = "128.downloadming1.com/bollywood%20mp3/Ekk%20Deewana%20Tha%20(2012)/01%20-%20Kya%20Hai%20Mohabbat.mp3";
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();  
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(url);   
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);   
            mp.prepare(); 
            mp.start(); 
            } catch (Exception e){ 
            Log.i("Exception", "Exception in streaming mediaplayer e = " + e);
       }
    }***
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to Anton's answer. prepare() function on Mediaplayer is synchronous which will block your UI thread.  So its better to use setonpreparelistner and start your media player on onpreparelistner().

Answer (score 0):

You code is ok, but i think, that you must add to url "http://". This must work.

UPD: if this don't work - write you exception.

Comment: :-). This thing is giving me much headache.Thanks